# How to show $\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^3=(xy)^3=1\rangle$ is presentation of an infinite group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, infinite-groups

> How to show $\langle x,y \mid x^3=y^3=(xy)^3=1 \rangle$ is presentation of an infinite group?

This is a result in textbook, but I do not understand the rationale.

Comment: What was the given rationale that you do not understand?

Comment: Also this question is already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1897367/trying-to-prove-that-h-langle-a-ba3-b3-ab3-1-rangle-is-a-group-of?rq=1).